# How to create a firefox plugin?

Tags: firefox, plugins

I have to create a Firefox plugin. I am a newbie and have no idea about it.

Please provide me information about the following:

1. Skill/programming language requirements
2. Any good and simple tutorials<
3. Sample code and steps to execute it
4. Difference between firefox plugin,add-on and extension

Comment: [How to developer a firefox extension](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/06/05/how-to-develop-firefox-extension/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Mozilla Developer network for documentation and other stuffs.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension)